# Why do I briefly see a black srceen with white writing which then disappears when trying to install Ubuntu on an HP Pavilion G7?

Tags: 11.10, installation, nomodeset

I recently bought a HP Pavilion G7 laptop.
I made a nice Ubuntu 11.10 USB using pendrivelinux.
When I try to install it a black screen with white letters appears (like normally) but disappears again. Then my screen is turning off then nothing happens any more.

What is the problem?
I've read about nomodeset or something like that but how do you do it? I don't have the option when I try to install.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Ubuntu Community Documentation on Boot Options](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Changing_the_CD.27s_Default_Boot_Options)

*Excerpt from it:*

> To supplement the main boot options, the F1-F6 keys provide additional
> information and boot options for special circumstances. These options
> are accessed by pressing any key before the Welcome screen appears.
> Pressing the ESC key or selecting a language will display the main
> screen.
>
> **F6.** Other Options. ACPI (Advanced Configuration and Power Interface) and EDD (Enhanced Disk Drive) options which may help if
> your computer does not support or has problems with these systems.
> Highlight the selection and press the ENTER key or SPACE key to select
> it. An "X" will appear, indicating selection. Multiple items can be
> selected from this popup menu. Hit ESC to leave the popup menu. The
> selections are retained at the time the user presses the ESC key.

[image: F6 Screenshot]

Hope that helped.

Comment: Normally dont just link stuff on an answer, if you think the information on that page is relevant to the problem the user is facing write down the most important steps that he needs to use to solve his problem and add a link to the source of the information on your answer. www.google.com is not the answer for anything.